# Can't Download JavaScript API from npm

Tags: javascript, here-api

I've tried following the documentation https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.20.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started-bundling.html to register the HERE package with npm and then download and install it. It seems to register (doesn't give an error), but when trying to install I get an error "'@here/maps-api-for-javascript@latest' is not in the npm registry."

I'm surprised I can't find an npm package published by HERE in npm itself, given it is a common way to install things these days.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing the API following documentation you provided and all worked fine.

It looks like you forgot to add here public registry to NPM configuration:

```
npm config set @here:registry https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/api/npm/maps-api-for-javascript/
```

Comment: As I said, I did register it as you stated.  Still didn't work.

Comment: Can you please share all the steps you did to be able to reproduce your use.